# Looking for a more elegant way to display list of passwords

Tags: javascript, function

I'm currently using a series of if-else statements to display a list of comma separated values that are populated from a list. It works fine, but I would like to use some thing a bit cleaner and better looking, but I can't figure out the best approach

I thought maybe I could use a FOR loop to create the the variable names(targetData.Password1, targetData.Password2...) My thinking, was to generate the numbers 1-15 and then concatenate the text "targetData.Password" to get the desired result, but that didn't feel right. I know there has to be a cleaner solution, but I'm not sure how to get there. Not necessarily looking for the answer, just a direction. Any ideas are appreciated

This is what I am using:

```
<% if ( targetData.Password1 != 0) { %>
<% if ( targetData.Password2 != 0) { %> <% if ( targetData.Password2 != 0) { %>Passwords<%}else{%>Password<%}%>: <%= targetData.Password1 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password1%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password3 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password2 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password2%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password4 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password3 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password3%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password5 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password4 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password4%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password6 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password5 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password5%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password7 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password6 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password6%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password8 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password7 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password7%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password9 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password8 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password8%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password10 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password9 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password9%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password11 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password10 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password10%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password12 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password11 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password11%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password13 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password12 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password12%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password14 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password13 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password13%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password15 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password14 + ", " %> <%}else{%> <%= targetData.Password14%><%}%> <% if ( targetData.Password15 != 0) { %> <%= targetData.Password15 %> <%}else{%><%}%>
```

I'm hoping to find an elegant way to get this result:

Passcodes : 13254A, 354q66, 625a5a, t35t, 354q66, 354q67, 354q68, 354q69, 354q70, 354q71, 354q72, 354q73, 354q74, 354q75, 354q76

Comment: Probably easier to change `targetData` to have the password in an array or something similar, so you can just iterate it

Comment: The concept of display of passwords just sounds like a poor thing to do.

Comment: From what I understand you have no reason to be using a key for the password (password1), why not just put them into an array and then loop through array to display them?

Comment: are these "values" not inside quotes?

Comment: Let me clarify, if I can, these are (<%= targetData.Password1 %>) are variable placeholders. They will coincide with a column in a file that is uploaded to the system. So <%= targetData.Password1 %>, when rendered will be, for example, 123abc. Instead of having to do 16 if-else statements. I was wondering if there was a function I could build to take the place of a long if-else statement? I'm sorry if I'm not making sense.

Comment: What I am envisioning is building something like this:

<%var passcall = function(password){%> <%if(password != 0){%>
Passcode:  <%=password%>
<%}else{%><%};%> <%};%>

I can then call the function like this:

<%passcall(**targetData.Password1**);%>

but instead of **Password1**, I can pass in the catch all Password object we've created

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the object property names then reduce that to valid values from the object, then use `join(', ')` to create string

I only went up to 6, adjust accordingly

```js
const propNames = Array.from({length:6}, (_, i) => `Password${i+1}`)

const passArray = propNames.reduce((a, c) => data[c] === 0 ? a : a.concat(data[c]), [])

console.log(passArray.join(', '))
```

```html
<script>
  const data = {
    Password1: 1,
    Password2: 2,
    Password3: 0,
    Password4: 4,
    Password5: 0,
    Password6: 6
  }
</script>
```